# Finding a route along points of interest

Tags: algorithm, graph, dictionary, routes, path-finding

I have a map with a destination (the red dot below), and a number of points of interest (the yellow, green and blue dots).

[image: map1]

I'm trying to find a path to the destination, but the starting point is undefined - I just want it to pass as many of the points of interest as possible, without the route being to circuitous.

For example the following (pink line) would be a good route in this case:

[image: map2]

The yellow dot is the POI furthest away from the destination (not useful in this case), the green ones are the four next furthest away.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm which would be suitable for this?

Is this a suitable problem to turn into a graph? The "not too circuitous" requirement seems to suggest that, but how would I reconcile that with wanting to pass as many POIs as possible along the way?

Edit: To clarify the "not too circuitous" requirement. I just want it to be a plausible route, for example turning a maximum of 90 degrees for the sum of all the corners. The POIs will always be nearby the destination so length isn't really an issue.

Comment: Finding an optimal path is NP-Hard, it is pretty much a variation of Traveling Salesman Problem, are you familiar with it?

Comment: As @amit states above, that would be a [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).  "As many POIs as possible" is always all of them, unless you set conditions to dismiss points, ie. maximum length of journey, etc.

Comment: `...the starting point is undefined...` use the destination as starting point if the graph is undirected.

Comment: "As many POIs as possible". Do you have a constraint like elapsed distance?

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback! @Orbling Let's say I need to pass at least 15 POIs - "maximum length of journey" does sound like my kind of restriction, could maybe have maximum heading change of 90 degrees or something.

Comment: @UmNyobe using the destination as a starting point does sound like a good idea, thanks :)

Comment: Suggest if you write an algorithm, it can take basic constraints like number of points min and max journey length.  Of course, if you specify both, there may be no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can definetly be reduced to a graph `G=(V,E)` where `V` are all your POI, and `E` in this case is `V x V` (edge between all vertices). You also need to produce a weight function `w:E->R` such that `w(u,v) = distance between u and v`

The problem is actually a variation of the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), so it is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) (So there is no known polynomial solution) - but have a look around, there are many [heuristics for this problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms).

Also - if you do not expect many POIs (say 20-30) - a dynamic programming solution can be used to find the optimal path between all points.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could turn it into a graph, assigning a negative weight to each of the points of interest (probably by reducing the value of any edge leading into that point) and then plugging said graph into the Bellman-Ford algorithm][1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), which permits negative-length edges. The only problem might come if two POIs are very close together, so some sort of pruning method might possibly be required.